# Array to Array-- incompatible types in assignment of 'int*' to 'int error in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

hello i want to assing return array from method to an array. My codes here. how can assing array to array like this?

method change codes:

```
int* change (int array[], int index1, int index2) {

    int temp;

    temp = array[index1];
    array[index1] = array[index2];
    array[index2] = temp;

iter++;

    return array;
}
```

method combine's codes here:

```
static void combine(int mat[], int len) {

    if(ok)
    return;

    int array[len];
    *array = *mat;


    if (len <= sat * sut) {

        for (int i = len; i < sat * sut - 1; i++) {

            for (int j = i; j < sat * sut; j++) {

             // this is error row
             combine(array, len + 1);

           array = change(array, i, j);

                if (isAcceptable(array) == "ACCEPTABLE") {

                    int accepted[sat*sut];
                    *accepted = *array;
                    ok = true;
                    return;
                }



            }
        }
    } else
        return;
 }
```

error row is here:

```
array = change(array, i, j);
```

error:  [Error] incompatible types in assignment of 'int*' to 'int [(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)len) + -1)) + 1)]'

how can i fix it?

Comment: An aside, but you might like to use `std::swap` in your `change` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
array = change(array, i, j);
```

As the error message says, you're trying to assign a pointer to an array, which makes no sense. There's no need for that; just call the function to change the array:

```
change(array, i, j);
```

and change the function to return `void` - there's no point simply passing back one of the arguments, since the caller already knows what is was. Or don't bother writing a function at all:

```
std::swap(array[i], array[j]);
```

Also, this looks a bit dodgy:

```
*array = *mat;
```

Perhaps you think this copies the entire array into `array`; it doesn't, it only copies the first element. To copy the array, do

```
std::copy(mat, mat+len, array);
```

or better still, use a standard container rather than a non-standard variable-length array:

```
std::vector<int> array(mat, mat+len);
```